# Force a .dll to change it's version?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, ninject

I got weird problem. I got an asp.net mvc 3 application that uses ninject version 2.0 but I want to upgrade it to version 2.2. but everytime I remove it and add the new .dll it keeps telling I am still using version version 2.0. and I have no clue why.

I don't know where it is getting that number from. I made a blank asp.net mvc application and added the new version and it says it is version 2.2.

So why does my application keep thinking everything I give it is version 2.0?

Another thing.

It's thinks the run time version is v2.0.50727 the one in my test application has v4.0.30319

Comment: How are you adding the reference?  Are you using "Add Library Package" feature to download the assembly?

Comment: @ Kyle Trauberman - Tried through nuget so ya "Add Library Package Reference" and downloaded ninject. I tried going to ninject site and download the "Ninject-2.2.0.0-release-net-4.0" and then went "Add Reference" and both come up with the same result.

Comment: You mention that the runtime version shows as 2.0.  Where do you see that?  Can you right click on your project, go to properties, and verify that your target framework is set to ".NET Framework 4"?

Comment: @ Kyle Trauberman - Yep I am targeting .net 4.0 framework and seems like all the other .dlls like system.Web.MVC are on 4.0

Comment: Is the updated Ninject assembly in the GAC on your machine?  Nuget stores a list of your installed assemblies in a "packages.config" file in your project.  What version does it show for ninject in that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have another project that references the old version of ninject, and at runtime it's resolving to that dependency instead of the one you think it is.

Comment: I agree with Chris. Your project refers another project, and 2nd project has a reference to old version of ninject.

Answer (score 2):

Open up the project file in a texteditor and make sure that the reference is correct. Remove any `HintPath` tag if it's present.

If this do not work, try checking the location of the loaded assembly.

```
string location = typeof(TypeInNinjectAssembly).Assembly.Location
```